# How to handling error on objectionjs with nestjs exception filters?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, objection.js

I used Objection.js as ORM for my Nest.js app. I tried to implement global error handling for both Http exception and Objection Error (ORM / Database Error). Suppose I make a mistake inserting a same unique value, it would throw `UniqueViolationError`. But every time I throw error on the `users.service.ts` (users module service) part of the app, on the service the error still an instance of `UniqueViolationError` but on filters it became the instance of `HttpExceptionError` thus my filters won't work. Here is the full code :

errors.filters.ts

```
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  InternalServerErrorException,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import {
  ValidationError,
  NotFoundError,
  DBError,
  ConstraintViolationError,
  UniqueViolationError,
  NotNullViolationError,
  ForeignKeyViolationError,
  CheckViolationError,
  DataError,
} from 'objection';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: InternalServerErrorException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();

    // All the errors here are instance of HttpException, it shouldn't be :(

    if (exception instanceof ValidationError) {
      switch (exception.type) {
        case 'ModelValidation':
          response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: exception.message,
            type: exception.type,
            data: exception.data,
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            path: request.url,
          });
          break;
        case 'RelationExpression':
          response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: exception.message,
            type: 'RelationExpression',
            data: {},
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            path: request.url,
          });
          break;
        case 'UnallowedRelation':
          response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: exception.message,
            type: exception.type,
            data: {},
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            path: request.url,
          });
          break;
        case 'InvalidGraph':
          response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: exception.message,
            type: exception.type,
            data: {},
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            path: request.url,
          });
          break;
        default:
          response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: exception.message,
            type: 'UnknownValidationError',
            data: {},
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            path: request.url,
          });
          break;
      }
    } else if (exception instanceof ConstraintViolationError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'ConstraintViolation',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof DBError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'UnknownDBError',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof DataError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'InvalidData',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof CheckViolationError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'CheckViolation',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof ForeignKeyViolationError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'ForeignKeyViolation',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof NotNullViolationError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'NotNullViolation',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof UniqueViolationError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
        message: exception.message,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        type: 'UniqueViolation',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof NotFoundError) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: exception.message,
        type: 'NotFound',
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
        message: exception.message,
        statusCode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        type: 'HttpServerError',
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
    } else {
      response.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
        type: 'UnknownErrorServer',
        statusCode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import * as requestIp from 'request-ip';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './filters/errors.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(requestIp.mw());
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());

  // swagger documentations
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('SWAGGER')
    .setDescription('SWWAAAAG')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);

  await app.listen(4040);
}
bootstrap();
```

functions on users.service.ts

```
try {
  await this.modelQuery.query().insert({ name: 'Same name' })
} catch (error) {
  // in here still UniqueViolationError
  throm new Error(error)
}
```

Why the error instance changed and how to make it not change? What do I do wrong here?

Comment: In your try catch, the error is of type `UniqueViolationError` which is a type of `ValidationError`, right?

Comment: I don't think so after reading the definition file, `UniqueViolationError` are actually using `db-errors` package.

Comment: In my try catch the error aren't the instance of `ValidationError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all of your checks are set up properly. What's happening though is you're creating a new error object and throwing *that* instead of throwing the original error object, meaning all of your `instanceof` checks are now useless, because you've thrown a `new Error()`. Either don't catch the error, or catch it and re-throw the original error after doing logging or whatever you need to.

Comment: Thanks it is actually that, so I catch the error on service and controller. The controller respond with `HttpException` that's why it always the instance of `HttpException`.